# Replace decimal in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, decimal

I have two `html.textBoxFor`'s and do a subtraction between the two values, but the result still appears with a `.`, instead of a `,`. How can I solve this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#km_final").on('input', function () {
        sumCal();
    });

    $("#km_inicial").on('input', function () {
        sumCal();
    });

    function sumCal() {
        var km1 = parseFloat($("#km_inicial").val().replace(",","."));
        var km2 = parseFloat($("#km_final").val().replace(",", "."));
        var result = (km2) - (km1);

        if (!isNaN(result)) {
            $("#extensao").val(result);
        } else {
            $("#extensao").val(0);
        }

    }

});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide example input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correctly converting your inputs into genuine numbers by translating the `,`s into `.`s, but after calculating the correct floating number you're not translating the `.`s back into `,`s: **[Working solution](http://jsfiddle.net/92UBf/1/)**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#km_final").on('input', function () {
        sumCal();
    });

    $("#km_inicial").on('input', function () {
        sumCal();
    });

    function sumCal() {

        var km1 = parseFloat($("#km_inicial").val().replace(",", "."));
        var km2 = parseFloat($("#km_final").val().replace(",", "."));
        var result = km2 - km1;
        if (!isNaN(result)) {
            $("#extensao").val(result.toString().replace(".", ","));
        } else {
            $("#extensao").val(0);
        }    
    }   
});
```